# Are there any matter examples for speaker devices?

Tags: esp32, google-home, speaker

I can't find any speaker examples in the SDK yet, but I believe this is a supported device type at this time?

Answer (score -1):

As of the current state of the Connected Home over IP (CHIP) SDK, there doesn't appear to be specific [example](https://github.com/project-chip/connectedhomeip/tree/master/examples) for speakers.

You can consider using the lighting example. The lighting example often includes clusters for level control and on/off functionalities, which can be adapted for controlling speakers. The concepts of cluster control and device on/off can be shared between lighting and audio devices.

Modify your code to suit the requirements of an audio device. You may need to adapt the clusters and commands to handle audio-related functionalities such as volume control, play/pause, and other relevant features.